# Node.js Decrypt encrypted file having salt

Tags: node.js, encryption

So I have this data

```
{"encryption_iv":"ag5BHpO+NfmChFZXSr4kCA==","encryption_salt":"fiGyeCMwtWc=","filename":"file.maFile"}
```

and I want to decrypt this data with the key and salt I have but I have no idea how to make it. I tried it with nodejs plugin `file-encryptor` but it didn't worked.

```
    const encryptor = require('file-encryptor');

var text = encryptor.decryptFile('./maFiles/***.maFile', './maFiles/output_file.txt', 'dHM8e22vEoc=', function(err) {
    // Decryption complete.
    console.error(err);
});

console.log(text);
```

Comment: A "salt" is usually combined with a passphrase through a Key Derivation Function to generate the actual encryption key. You need to know the password and the KDF used to generate the key in order to decrypt the contents.

Comment: @Andy I know the password too, but how to decrypt having these?

Comment: We don't have enough information (which KDF used, cipher block mode of operation, etc.) to fully answer. My suggestions would be:

1. Look at the encrypting code/ talk to whoever is encrypting the data about their process.
2. Look for examples of file-encryptor usage, because it's unfortunately common that developers just copy the tutorial and deploy to production.
3. Try deriving the key with the salt, password, and common KDFs (SHA-n, PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt). This is effectively "high knowledge cracking", so be prepared to expend some resources on this via hashcat or Jack the Ripper.

Comment: I never had to decrypt a encrypted file/var but using node I've used crypto. I found a tutorial, I do not post as answer cause Idk if it works, just a suggestion. Crypto instead of Decrypt:
http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/

Comment: @Andy the file is encrypted with the program which I found in github [github link](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamDesktopAuthenticator/blob/master/Steam%20Desktop%20Authenticator/ImportAccountForm.cs#L178) could it be helpfull?

Answer (score 2):

After further analysis of the provided source, you can see from [`FileEncryptor.cs`](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamDesktopAuthenticator/blob/master/Steam%20Desktop%20Authenticator/FileEncryptor.cs#L20) that the KDF is PBKDF2 with 50k iterations. So you need to use a JS implementation of PBKDF2, and provide it the password, salt, iteration count, and desired key length as parameters. This will return the actual encryption key used. Then decode the cipher bytes from Base64 encoding to raw binary, and decrypt using `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding`.